# How to get C2DM auth token?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, auth-token

I'm working on android c2dm for a while.

Last week, I got registration id in the emulator's logcat, but I still can not get auth token.

And there are some error & warning messages in my logcat:

```
**02-15 10:41:39.092: WARN/DefaultRequestDirector(176): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}**

**02-15 10:41:39.102: ERROR/C2DMRegistrar(176): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException**

02-15 10:41:42.601: INFO/System.out(487): APA91bF_B-VagQ9pO1toPGGMUYMBAURfgyL1AAa6Y8fn5WKf2DSj0qJINnlJIQ_MRoJBVdo9hMvJu1hLjHid-rk37zOFuOaY5A

02-15 10:41:42.601: INFO/System.out(487): [ 02-15 10:41:42.601   487:0x1f3 I/1registrationid=APA91bF_B-VagQ9pO1toPGGMUYMBAURfgyL1AAa6Y8fn5WKf2DSj0qJINnlJIQ_MRoJBVdo9hMvJAPA91bF_B-VagQ9pO1toPGGMUYMBAURfgyL1AAa6Y8fn5WKf2DSj0qJINnlJIQ_MRoJBVdo9hMvJu1hLjHid-rk37zOFuOaY5A

02-15 10:41:42.642: INFO/C2DMReceiver-onRegistered(487): APA91bF_B-VagQ9pO1toPGGMUYMBAURfgyL1AAa6Y8fn5WKf2DSj0qJINnlJIQ_MRoJBVdo9hMvJu1hLjHid-rk37zOFuOaY5A

**02-15 10:41:42.713: WARN/DeviceRegistrar(487): 2Registration error the name must not be empty: null**
```

Now I'm trying to use the chrometophone's source code, but still don't get auth token...

Am I miss something and how can I get the auth token?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sending messages from one device to another? The auth token is typically needed on a Web server that generates messages. The device does not need the auth token - it gets the registration ID, passes it to the server and expects the messages.